# Issues with creating an event series

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I want to create a Google calendar event series for

> "every first sunday in all months"

Using CalendarApp.getCalendarById(testId).createEventSeries(...).

I try various combinations of CalendarApp.newRecurrence().add...only... but none of them works.
The Code:

```
function example () {

  var year=2022;
  var testId='cobugitj4b6dev17cghb78j3rc@group.calendar.google.com';
  var oneHour=60 * 60 * 1000
  var sunday=CalendarApp.Weekday.SUNDAY;
  var silvester=new Date(year, 11, 31, 23, 59, 0);
  var startDayTime=new Date(year, 0, 2, 19, 30, 0);
  var recurrenceWeekday=CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addWeeklyRule().onlyOnWeekday(sunday)
  var newEvent = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(testId).createEventSeries("Termin",
        startDayTime, new Date(startDayTime.getTime() + oneHour),
        recurrenceWeekday.until(silvester));
}
```

creates an event on each sunday. Which method shall I use to restrict the event only to the first sunday of each month?

It is no problem to create such an eventSerie online.

[image: EventSerie online]

The correct VCALENDAR-Entry looks like this:

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Vienna:20220102T193000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Vienna:20220102T203000
RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;COUNT=12;BYDAY=1SU
DTSTAMP:20200811T121708Z
UID:7ojdc1g1mfjov4m3ubtg7k8d5h@google.com
CREATED:20200811T120316Z
DESCRIPTION:
LAST-MODIFIED:20200811T121423Z
LOCATION:FranZ
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:Termin_1
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
```

Comment: Welcome to stack please supply a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.  There is not enough code here to help you debug your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can find documentation about recurring Google Calendar API events [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/recurringevents)
- The [Events resource](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#recurrence) spevifies:

> List of RRULE, EXRULE, RDATE and EXDATE lines for a recurring event, as specified in RFC5545. Note that DTSTART and DTEND lines are not allowed in this field; event start and end times are specified in the start and end fields. This field is omitted for single events or instances of recurring events.

- whereby there is a detailed documentation about [RFC5545](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.5)

### For your specific query the recurernce rule would be:

`"RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=SU;BYSETPOS=1"`

- This kind of syntax is not supported by CalendarApp

- In order to sue it you need to enable the [Advanced Calendar Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar)
- In order to [enable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services) it, please go on `Resources > Advanced Google services.`

After this you can use the Advanced Calendar as following:

```
function example() {
  var testId='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
  var silvester="20221231";
  var resource = {
    "start": {
      "date": "2020-09-06"
    },
    "end": {
      "date": "2020-09-06"
    },
    "recurrence": [
      "RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=SU;BYSETPOS=1;UNTIL=" + silvester
    ],
          "summary": "Termin"
  }
  Calendar.Events.insert(resource, testId);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought to be able to solve my problem. But I got the error "Beim API-Aufruf von "calendar.events.insert" ist dieser Fehler aufgetreten: Missing time zone definition for start time" using dateTime; start.toISOString() as described in the example of Advanced Calendar Service

Comment: If you want to use a `dateTime` instead of a `date`, you need to define also a `timeZone`: `{
  "start": {
    "dateTime": "",
    "timeZone": ""
  },
  "end": {
    "timeZone": "",
    "dateTime": ""
  },
  "recurrence": [
    "RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=SU;BYSETPOS=1;UNTIL=20201231"
  ],
  "summary": ""
}`, see [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert)